# Server Error in '/' Application, Cannot open database "" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have created a website using ASP.net with simple data connection which is working fine in localhost. when I want to publish the same, I am getting this error. "Cannot open database "Abcdb" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user '`XYZ-Domain\XYZ-SVR-01$`'.

1. I don't have the user '`XYZ-Domain\XYZ-SVR-01`$' in my SQL Server (SQL Express 2012).
2. I have my server in a virtual machine .
3. my connection string is "`Data Source=XYZ-05-VM1\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=Abcdb`".

do I have to create a user in my database as shown above or else can I use existing database user. I am very new to this technology. Kindly help me.

Comment: "Integrated Security" means use the windows account the site is running under to log into the database - that will be your account while debugging and the user for the AppPool when deployed. If your DB VM isn't tied to the same authority as your dev machine (ie a domain controller) integrated security is going to be awkward - you might be better off disabling it and using a username/password for the time being

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Abcdb;Integrated Security = SSPI"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the server could be reached and the database name is correct. The problem is that the login is invalid.
From the login name I suppose that you have set `Integrated Security=SSPI` in your connection string and therefore try to authenticate with the account that your application is running under at the SQL Server. On your development machine, this is your user account that on a typical developer machine will be granted high access rights to the local SQL Server.
After you have deployed your application to IIS, it will run in an AppPool that is basically a process under a specific user account (the AppPool account). You need to grant this user account access to the database. In your case, this account is the Network Service account of the server you have your application deployed to. So you need to either grant the Network Service account access to the database or follow this - cleaner - approach:

- Create a new Service account in your domain that is dedicated to your application.
- Configure your AppPool to run under this account. Assert that the account has the minimum amount of access rights on the server that is possible.
- Grant this account access to your database.

If you want to check the database connection settings, have a look at the connectionStrings section in your web.config. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows the available settings for SQL Server.